# Getting the charAt for two characters

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm trying to split a string into two-character blocks. I then want to find the position of the two characters in a character array. How do I do this in Java

```
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += 2) {

        // Split the message into substrings of 2
        String splitMessage = message.substring(i,+ i+2);
        System.out.println(splitMessage);
        //
        for (int j = 0; j < splitMessage.length(); j++) {
            int plainTxtCh = charSet.indexOf(splitMessage.charAt(j));
            System.out.println(plainTxtCh);
        }
```

which returns

```
xy
23
24
ed
4
3
dd
3
3
```

what I want to do is pair the two numbers together. So for example after xy, I would have one integer '2324' instead of two seperate integers.
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I want every two letters to be grouped into one integer according to their position in the alphabet string I made, so 'ed' = 43 dd='33' etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you actually want to do? What about `4` and `3`. Do you want to pair them as well? What about `ed` and `dd` ?

Comment: @user3437460, yea sorry, that was just an example string i tested with.. I want every two letters to be grouped into one integer according to their position in the alphabet string I made, so 'ed' = 43 dd='33' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try this:

```
String charset = "abc";
String message = "abcabcabca";

char[] msgArr = message.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < msgArr.length; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(msgArr[i] + "" + (i == msgArr.length - 1 ? "" : msgArr[i + 1]));
    System.out.println(charset.indexOf(msgArr[i]) + "" + (i == msgArr.length - 1 ? "" : charset.indexOf(msgArr[i + 1])));
}
```

The output is:

```
ab
01
ca
20
bc
12
ab
01
ca
20
```

Works with both odd and even message length :)

Comment: no. I create strings and write them into the console

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner for loop to this following:

```
for (int j = 0; j < splitMessage.length(); j++){
    int plainTxtCh = charSet.indexOf(splitMessage.charAt(j));
    System.out.print(plainTextCh);
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: thanks, how to i pair the line of integers into one whole integer?

Comment: it is not a large integer. It is a string (like "2324"). But you can parse into the Integer: Integer.parseInt("2324")

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern. Remember that when you'd like to find digits in your string, use:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(yourString);
```

Or you can delete "enter" between digits. Use this pattern to find you divided digits:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\s)(\\d+)");
```